# How much did medieval horse armor cost?

Tags: middle-ages, cavalry, armour, price

I have a number of sources I use to get examples & documentation of costs in the medieval period of knightly implements such as armor, weapons, horses, supplies, etc. However, all of my usual sources are failing me on the question of how much a set of horse armor (barding) would cost at the time.

Granted that there are lots of different styles and components crafted over the years; practically any type from the High to Late middle ages or Renaissance would be a helpful starting point. I'm looking for a specific citation (perhaps in an account-book or ledger from the time, such as exist for other examples of armor and horses) and a specific enumerated price point (e.g., "about as much as a car today" or "only the wealthy could afford it" are not helpful).

As a comparative example, below is an excerpt on medieval Armor from the "Medieval Sourcebook: Medieval Prices", compiled by Kenneth Hodges/Paul Halsall circa 2000, drawing on about ten different sources (currently [here](https://aemma.org/content/medievalprices.php)).

Note that due to the scarcity of documentation, we must accept that the best we can do is a handful of sketchy data across several centuries, from maybe only a few specialized book sources. Yet even this has been found useful to many people (this list has been duplicated on a number of internet sites over the years). I'm hoping someone knows of even one or two pieces of documentation for horse armor at this same level of detail and epoch.

[image: Medieval Sourcebook: Medieval Prices, excerpt from Armor section]

Do similar documented examples exist for the price of horse armor in the same time range (12th to 17th centuries)?

Comment: This takes me back to the great debate about the price of horse armor in 2006

Comment: According to Bethesda it was [500 gold](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Horse_Armor_Pack) (per, entirely cosmetic, set).

Comment: The problem with questions like this is the medieval period was a *long* time. During parts of it, particularly in the early period, much of Europe didn't even have the kind of money/market economy where it would make sense to talk about the market price for goods like this question wants to do. Most people operated on barter (including labor barter).

Comment: Can I suggest we pick a specific time, and I'll suggest "Battle of Agincourt" (or somewhere near it).

Comment: @SPavel: Is there a link to that somewhere?

Comment: I was looking at your Medieval Sourcebook link to see what sources the numbers were referencing, and unfortunately the sources listed are secondary sources. One that caught my attention, however, *[5] **The Armourer and his Craft from the XIth to the XVIth Century,** Charles ffoulkes, Dover, 1988 (orig. 1912)*. This has a lot of good information, *including some primary source and museum records*, concerning both regular and horse armour. You can find a copy on Project Guttenberg [here](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/60767/pg60767-images.html#Page_85)

Comment: If you already have a cost for knight armor (in the time and area of your choosing) you should get a good estimate for horse armor by comparing the two. It was all manual labor back then, so whether you pay a smith to make armor for a horse or a human, the difference is only in size and quantity of material needed.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to find one single clear citation from this 1967 PhD thesis:

WIEDEMER JR, JACK EARL. Arms and Armor in England, 1450-1471, their Cost and Distribution. University of Pennsylvania, 1967 (p. 60).

> At some time during the later 1460's, the earl of Oxford asked Sir
> John Paston to purchase three horse harnesses of the best quality for
> Oxford's use, adding that he was willing to pay up to £7. each for
> them, and that Lord Hastings had recently paid between £6. and £7. for
> one such harness. These figures prove that armor for a horse could
> cost as much as that for a man, which is probably another reason why
> horse armor seems to have been comparatively rare.

A footnote for this section cites *The Paston Letters A.D. 1422-1509*, ed. J. Gairdner. London: Chatto and Windus, 1904 ([Vol. 4: 686](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/41081/pg41081-images.html#note300_1)).

One note: The currency symbols in the typed thesis are hand-written and look to my eye like a "Z" with a horizontal crossbar through the middle. Based on surrounding context I'm pretty sure this is meant to be the symbol for pounds sterling (shown in my transcription above).

Comment: Text of the [Volume 4, #686](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/41081/pg41081-images.html#note300_1:~:text=300-,686,-THE%20EARL%20OF)

Comment: @justCal: Thanks for that, I accidentally included a footnote from one sentence earlier. Removed in an edit.

Comment: By the way, we like links here. If you have an online accessible source for the '67 thesis paper, please edit that into your answer.

Comment: @justCal: It's not available publicly. My academic librarian had to bend some rules to get me a copy.